# XPath: select children nodes of particular parent

Tags: xml, xpath

there are a few cases

Case A:

```
<Root>
  <Defaults Id="a"></Defaults>
</Root>
```

Case B:

```
<Root>
  <Repeat>
    <Defaults Id="b"></Defaults>
  </Repeat>
</Root>
```

Case C (number of nested "Repeat" might be unlimited):

```
<Root>
  <Repeat>
    <Repeat>
      <Repeat>
        <Defaults Id="c"></Defaults>
      </Repeat>
    </Repeat>
  </Repeat>
</Root>
```

Case D:

```
<Root>
  <Repeat>
    <Page Id="p1">
      <Defaults Id="d"></Defaults>
    </Page>
  </Repeat>
</Root>
```

I need XPath query that returns Defaults nodes that belong to Root element or located inside of Repeat nodes only. If at least one parent isn't Repeat node or Root, they shouldn't be included to the result. So result of query should return nodes from test cases A, B, C.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//Defaults[parent::Root or parent::Repeat]
```

will select all `Default` elements with a parent of `Root` or `Repeat`,

```
<Defaults Id="a"></Defaults>
<Defaults Id="b"></Defaults>
<Defaults Id="c"></Defaults>
```

as requested.